# AsyncFileUpload Dynamically add in custom control

Tags: c#, custom-controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Creating one custom control which will have the Async File Upload control.
But when i am trying add the Async FileUpload in a control not able to add getting Complie time error.
Following is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AjaxControlToolkit;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace SBITS.CustomControl
{
class CustomFileUpload:CompositeControl
{

    private AsyncFileUpload asyncFileUpload;

    private Image throbberImage;


    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {

        this.throbberImage = new Image();
        this.throbberImage.ImageUrl = Constant.THROBBER_IMAGE_PATH;
        this.Controls.Add(throbberImage);

        this.asyncFileUpload = new AsyncFileUpload();
        this.asyncFileUpload.ThrobberID = throbberImage.ID;
        this.Controls.Add(asyncFileUpload);
    }
}  }
```

getting error on this line

```
 this.Controls.Add(asyncFileUpload);
```

error screen

[image]

Compile time error

[image]

Comment: VS produces pair of error messages when faced with invalid arguments error. The second message tells what type method receives and what type it expects to receive. Can you show this compiler error too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the resolution for the issue 
just added the reference of `system.web.Extension` to my project and its done.